# Xcode force_load not working iOS

Tags: objective-c

I am using Xcode 4.6 and default compiler

Select the Build Settings tab, and make the following changes (again, substitute your J2ObjC's distribution directory for $distribution-path):

In Header Search Paths, add `"$distribution-path/include", then add "${DERIVED_FILES_DIR}"`.
In Library Search Paths, add `"$distribution-path/lib"`.
In Other Linker Flags, add `"-ljre_emul -ObjC -force_load $distribution-path/lib/libjre_emul.a". (jre_emul is J2ObjC's JRE emulation library).`

I same setting

```
"-ljre_emul -Wl-ObjC -force-load ${HOME}/Desktop/j2objc/lib/libjre_emul.a"
```

but

```
-[__NSCFConstantString trim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f89c8
2013-06-05 17:50:21.412 TESTJ2OJBC[885:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString trim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f89c8'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x314a63e7 0x391a1963 0x314a9f31 0x314a864d 0x31400208 0x61de3 0x716dd 0x9e3d9 0x9d9bf 0x9deeb 0x9d6ab 0x48fe1 0x48de1 0x332d4579 0x33314d59 0x33310af5 0x333521e1 0x48cab 0x33315aa1 0x33315625 0x3330d833 0x332b5d1f 0x332b57ad 0x332b51ef 0x34fcd5f7 0x34fcd227 0x3147b3e7 0x3147b38b 0x3147a20f 0x313ed23d 0x313ed0c9 0x3330c46d 0x333092b9 0x4899f 0x395ceb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception


__NSCFConstantString trim is 
NSString+JavaString.h  method
// String.trim()
- (NSString *)trim;
```

please teaching me

Comment: You've already asked this question.

Comment: this question is not a duplicate. Although the same errors are caused. This one is due to using j2objc and the other one is from missing linker files

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking a static library that contains class extensions in categories you need to specify the `-objc` flag to the linker. This forces it to load all objects from the library rather than only the ones that are referenced and therefore that the linker can identify as unresolved external symbols. Technically I think the linker could probably do a better job to identify these without needing to include everything, but it currently needs this flag.